# Relationship between Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

> Each of $n \ge 2$ people puts his or her name on a slip of paper (no two have
>   the same name). The slips of paper are shuffled in a hat, and then each person draws one
>   (uniformly at random at each stage, without replacement). Find the **standard deviation**
>   of the number of people who draw their own names.

First, I calculated the mean as follows:
Let $I_j$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ person gets their name. These are Bernoulli trials, thus making the probability $I_j \sim \operatorname{Bern}(\frac{1}{n})$. Thus, our mean is just $1$.

However, I'm having issues calculating the standard deviation. The formula for variance is $\mathbb{E}(X^2) - [\mathbb{E}(X)]^2$. We obviously know the second part of this equation, and for the first part, is the calculation just ($n^2 \times \frac1n$)? Thus $n$?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

$$X = \sum_{j=1}^n I_j$$

\begin{align}X^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^nI_j^2+\sum_{i\neq j} I_iI_j \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nI_j+\sum_{i\neq j} I_iI_j\end{align}

\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[X^2] &= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[I_j]+\sum_{i\neq j} Pr(I_i=1,I_j=1)\end{align}

Are you able to continue from here?

Hint: final answer does not depend on $n$.

Comment: Your "Pr" is P(I$_j$ = 1, I$_j$ = 1), just with different notation, correct?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing.